# $L^2(\mu)$ limit of a sequence of CDFs

Tags: probability-distributions

Let $(F_n)$ be a sequence of cumulative distribution functions (CDFs*). Let $\mu$ be a finite measure on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})$, and assume $\mu$ is equivalent to Lebesgue measure (notice that any CDF lies in $L^2(\mu)$). Assume $\Vert F_n - F\Vert_{L^2(\mu)}\rightarrow 0$, for some $[F]\in L^2(\mu)$. Can I find some $H\in[F]$ such that $H$ is also a CDF? In other words: is the set of CDFs closed in $L^2(\mu)$?

*A function $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is said to be a *cumulative distribution function* if:

1. $F$ is nondecreasing.
2. $F$ is right-continuous.
3. $\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}F(x) = 0$.
4. $\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}F(x) = 1$.

Comment: Can't you get $L^2$ convergence to the zero function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You still need some generalized notion of [tightness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tightness_of_measures) to conclude that $F$ is a CDF. For example, take $\mu$ to be lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$, and $F_n$ to be the CDF of $X_n=n$. Then $\|F_n-0\|_{L^2(\mu)}=0$

Comment: Remark: the example remains true if we substitute the above $\mu$ by any finite measure since $\Vert F_n - 0\Vert = \mu\left[n,+\infty\right)$